# Schur orthogonality proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Prop: For finite-dim representations of a finite gruop $G$ in which inner products have been introduced to make the representations unitary.

(a) if $(R_1,V_1)$ and $(R_2,V_2)$ are inequivalent and irreducible then

$\sum_{x\in G}(R_1(x)v_1,v_1') \overline{(R_2(x)v_2,v_2')} =0$.

---

The proof by Knapp basic algebra 
[image]

but I get lost of the first step. How can I get the $R_1(g)LR_2(g^{-1})=L$?

Then, I can understand the rest of the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$ R_1(g) L R_2(g^{-1}) = R_1(g) \left( \sum_{x \in G} R_1(x) l R_2(x^{-1}) \right) R_2(g^{-1}) = \\
\sum_{x \in G} R_1(g) R_1(x) l R_2(x^{-1}) R_2(g^{-1}) 
= \sum_{x \in G} R_1(gx) l R_2((gx)^{-1}).$$

Now let $y = gx$ and note that the map $x \mapsto gx$ is a bijection of $G$ with itself (so that when $x$ "runs" over all elements of $G$ once, so does $y = gx$). Thus, we can perform the change of variables and conclude that

$$ \sum_{x \in G} R_1(gx) l R_2((gx)^{-1}) = \sum_{y \in G} R_1(y) l R_2(y^{-1}) = L. $$